# Calculate amount between a range of dates

Tags: python, pandas, odoo, odoo-14

So i have this problem, I want to calculate an amount of money between the first and last day of the month.

Example:
I am going to receive a payment of $1000 for a job that is going to take 3 months but i want to subtract the amount I'm going to receive each month lets say I work 8 a day 5 days a week.

```
def get_montly_adjustments(self, start_date, end_date, project_id):
        # calculating the month first day and last day
        month_range = monthrange(year, month)
        first_day_month_str = "%s-%s-01" % (year, month)
        last_day_month_str = "%s-%s-01" % (year, month, month_range[1])
        month_first_day = datetime.strptime(first_day_month_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
        month_last_day = datetime.strptime(last_day_month_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I have created a function to calculate the first and last day of the month but im looking for an idea on how to calculate the amount?

Thanks!.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's not convert a date to string and parse it back. We can do better:

```
def get_montly_adjustments(self, start_date, end_date, project_id):
    first_of_month = date(start_date.year, start_date.month, 1)
    last_of_month = date(start_date.year, start_date.month + 1, 1) + timedelta(-1)
```

Assuming that workdays are Monday through Friday, I get

```
    day = first_of_month
    workdays = 0
    while day <= last_of_month:
        if day.weekday() not in [5, 6]:  # Saturday, Sunday
            workdays += 1
        day += timedelta(1)
    print(f"workdays: {workdays}")
```

It's not clear to me how you expect to be paid. This probably depends on country and law regulations. One approach would be as follows

Starting on 2021-06-09, work until 2021-09-08 (3 months) gives 4 payments:

- 9 to 30 in June = 22 days (= x workdays)
- 1 to 31 in July = 31 days (= x workdays)
- 1 to 31 in August = 31 days (= x workdays)
- 1 to 8 in September = 8 days (= x workdays)

Code for that:

```
def get_montly_adjustments(self, start_date, end_date, project_id):
    # Calculate all workdays in project range
    day = start_date
    last_of_month = date(day.year, day.month + 1, 1) + timedelta(-1)
    workdays = 0
    workdayspermonth = []
    while day <= end_date:
        if day.weekday() not in [5, 6]:
            workdays += 1

        if day == last_of_month or day == end_date:
            workdayspermonth.append(workdays)
            workdays = 0
            last_of_month = date(day.year, day.month + 2, 1) + timedelta(-1)  # next last of month
        day += timedelta(1)

    # Get to the money
    monthnames = {1: "Jan", 2: "Feb", 3: "Mar", 4: "Apr", 5: "May", 6: "Jun", 7: "Jul", 8: "Aug", 9: "Sep", 10: "Oct",
                  11: "Nov", 12: "Dec"}
    totalworkdays = sum(workdayspermonth)
    print(f"Total workdays: {totalworkdays}")
    moneyperday = 1000 / totalworkdays
    print(f"That's an awesome {moneyperday:.2f} USD per day")
    for month in range(len(workdayspermonth)):
        workdays = workdayspermonth[month]
        print(f"Get paid! {workdays * moneyperday:.2f} USD for {workdays} workdays in {monthnames[start_date.month + month]}")
```

Output for

```
get_montly_adjustments(None, date(2021, 6, 9), date(2021, 9, 9), 815)
```

is

```
Total workdays: 67
That's an awesome 14.93 USD per day
Get paid! 238.81 USD for 16 workdays in Jun
Get paid! 328.36 USD for 22 workdays in Jul
Get paid! 328.36 USD for 22 workdays in Aug
Get paid! 104.48 USD for 7 workdays in Sep
```

Comment: Thank you, for the moment this data we capture is just going  to be used for reporting, thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use pandas date range but perhaps someone can modify it for datetime.

create the days in the month range:

```
days = pd.date_range("01/01/2021", "03/01/2021", freq="D")
```

state what days you work:

```
working_days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"]
```

Find the days in the month you would work in that time:

```
worked_days = days[days.strftime('%a').isin(days_worked)]
```

multiply the number of days worked by your price per day:

```
cost = len(worked_days)*8*price_per_hour
```

You may need to take into account bank holidays, days off etc.